# Why the main thread didn't exit correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running two Kafka Consumer on two different threads, plus the main thread.

I exit the main thread safely using the countdown, but it exited with this message:

```
Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

This is my simple code, you can run it directly:

```
public class ConsumerDemoWithThreads {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerDemoWithThreads.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "mygroup");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        String topic = "myopic";
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        ConsumerThread thread1 = new ConsumerThread(latch, properties, topic);
        ConsumerThread thread2 = new ConsumerThread(latch, properties, topic);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            logger.info("Caught a killing signal");
            thread1.shutdown();
            thread2.shutdown();
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            logger.info("Application has exited!");
        }));
        latch.await();
        logger.info("Shutting down the application...");
    }

    static class ConsumerThread extends Thread {
        private final String topic;
        private final Properties properties;
        private final CountDownLatch latch;
        private final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
        private final Logger logger;

        public ConsumerThread(CountDownLatch latch, Properties properties, String topic) {
            this.latch = latch;
            this.topic = topic;
            this.properties = properties;
            this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerThread.class.getName() + "_" + getName());
            this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(this.properties);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {


            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(this.topic));
            try {
                while (true) {
                    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
                    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                        logger.info("Key = " + record.key());
                        logger.info("Value = " + record.value());
                        logger.info("Partition = " + record.partition());
                    }
                }
            } catch (WakeupException ex) {
                logger.info("Received shutdown signal");
                this.latch.countDown();
            }

        }

        private void shutdown() {
            this.consumer.wakeup();
        }
    }
}
```

The application exists with the following logs:

```
14:12:59.728 [Thread-3] INFO  c.m.ConsumerDemoWithThreads - Caught a killing signal
14:12:59.729 [Thread-2] INFO  c.m.ConsumerDemoWithThreads$ConsumerThread_Thread-2 - Received shutdown signal
14:12:59.729 [Thread-0] INFO  c.m.ConsumerDemoWithThreads$ConsumerThread_Thread-0 - Received shutdown signal
14:12:59.729 [Thread-3] INFO  c.m.ConsumerDemoWithThreads - Application has exited!
14:12:59.729 [main] INFO  c.m.ConsumerDemoWithThreads - Shutting down the application...

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

Comment: Looking for help

Comment: What is running your application.  The SIGINT is probably coming from something external.  Are you running in a container for example?

Comment: @Gray no I am on my local laptop. running it from My IDE

Comment: Looking for help please